# cd directory in opened zip file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file, zip

I have a zip file which on first 'level' contains only directory. Something like:

some_file.zip

/ Opened file (level 1)

-> Directory/

/ level 2

-> file.txt

-> file2.txt

Can somebody write code how to `cd` to a `Directory\` and list all entries?

I have written code but it doesnt work:

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

Zip::ZipFile.open("./some_file.zip") do |zipfile|
  zipfile.each_with_index do |file, index|
    puts "inspect file == #{file.inspect}"
    puts "entries == #{ zipfile.entries }"
    entries = zipfile.entries
    puts "zipfile.open file #{ zipfile.read(file) }"
  end
end
```

PS I use `rubyzip` https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems a bit too complicated. Suppose you have a zip file like this:

```
$ mkdir data
$ cd data
$ touch foo bar baz
$ cd ..
$ zip -r data.zip data/
```

Then you can list the contents of the zip file using the `entries` method like in the following example:

```
require 'zip/zip'

zip = Zip::ZipFile.open('data.zip')
zip.entries.each do |entry|
  puts entry
end
```

This little example produces the following output:

```
data/
data/bar
data/baz
data/foo
```